# Как перезапускать скрипт в случае ошибки?

Tags: python

```
def do_some_work():   # Функция с периодически запускающимся 'скриптом'
   
     print("Hello, World!")


while True:   # Бесконечный цикл в котором
    do_some_work()   # Мы запускаем основной код
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйся механизмом исключений:

```
def do_some_work():   # Функция с периодически запускающимся 'скриптом'
    print("Hello, World!")
    
    
while True:   # Бесконечный цикл в котором
    try:
        do_some_work()   # Мы запускаем основной код    
    except:
        print(f'some error')
```